# Removing filter options from React Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid, react-data-table-component

How can I remove filter options from React Data Grids filters? For example when I do FilterEditior: SelectFilter it shows "Contains", "Does not contain", "Equal" etc but I only want the filtering options to be "Contains" and "Equal". I can only find a way to add filtering options with renderColumContextMenu but none to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Their `renderColumnContextMenu` property allows customization of the **Context Menu** (the menu at the top of each column with a "3 line" icon).

It sounds like you want `renderColumnFilterContextMenu`, which allows customization of the **Filter Context Menu** (the menu with "Not in list" etc). They provide an example here: https://reactdatagrid.io/docs/api-reference#props-renderColumnFilterContextMenu.

For example to remove their "Not in list" menu item, modify the `renderColumnFilterContextMenu` function from that example as follows:

```
const renderColumnFilterContextMenu = useCallback((menuProps, { 
  cellProps }) => {
    // Limit this change to the specific column,
    // by referring to its id or name from your columns array.
    if (cellProps.id === 'country') {
      menuProps.items = menuProps.items.filter((item) => item.itemId !== 'operator-notinlist');
    }
}, []);
```

*Note: I know you specifically asked about the "Does not contain" menu item, but in their 4.21.0 community/enterprise versions I see it as "Not in list".*

Comment: I was looking to remove filters that were in the list already. So things like "contains", "equals", "empty" as they're not useful in some of my use cases.